# A logic error. canvas: balls physics, bounce

Tags: javascript, html-canvas, gameobject, objects

Hi I was making a program that simulate a bunch of balls bouncing, but the problem is some balls got stuck to the floor. Since it's a logic error, it is kind of difficult to find. Can someone help, I let the snipper code below thanks.

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var canvas = {};
var ball = [];

canvas.obj = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.ctx = canvas.obj.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.obj.width;
canvas.height = canvas.obj.height;
canvas.clear = function() {
  canvas.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
canvas.preferences = function() {
  canvas.ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(210,210,210)';
  canvas.ctx.lineWidth = 1;
};

const FRICTION = .9;
const MIN_ACCELERATION = 1;
const FRICTION_INCREASE = .015;
const DIST = 20;
const N_BALLS = 50; // BALLS NUMBER
const GROUND = canvas.height;

var Object = function() {
  this.yVel = 0;
  this.gForce = 0.2;
  this.friction = FRICTION;
  this.full = false;
  this.run = true;

  this.draw = function() {
    canvas.ctx.beginPath();
    canvas.ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radio, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    canvas.ctx.stroke();
  };

  this.physics = function() {

    this.y += this.yVel;

    if (this.y + this.radio < GROUND) {
      this.yVel += this.gForce;
    } else if (this.y + this.radio > GROUND && this.yVel > MIN_ACCELERATION) {
      this.yVel *= -this.friction;
      this.y = GROUND - this.radio;
      this.friction -= FRICTION_INCREASE;
    } else {
      this.yVel = 0;
      this.y = GROUND - this.radio;
      this.run = false;
    }
  };
};

var generateBalls = function(p) {

  var i, random;

  for (i = 0; i < N_BALLS; i++) {
    p[i] = new Object();

    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18) + 5;
    p[i].radio = random;

    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 22) + 1;
    p[i].x = DIST * random;

    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
    p[i].y = DIST * random;

  }
};

var drawBalls = function() {
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < N_BALLS; i++) {
    ball[i].draw();
  }
};

var applyPhysics = function() {
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < N_BALLS; i++) {
    ball[i].physics();
  }
};

generateBalls(ball);
canvas.preferences();
var program = setInterval(function() {

  canvas.clear();
  drawBalls();
  applyPhysics();

}, 1000 / 60);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid rgb(210, 210, 210);
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="400"></canvas>
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: It's really hard to find a logic error in a spanish code, can you please translate it?

Comment: yes sorry Im gonna do it, I got to dinner.

Comment: @Bálint I have posted an edit translating the code to English. Spanish is my first language and I have experience with Javascript games. Vincent, you can [edit](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/141772/edit) your question anytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To figure out what is going on, I started looking at the code that moves the balls. In this case it is `physics` (`fisicas`). I see two coditionals where you stop the ball:

```
if (this.y + this.radio < GROUND) {
  this.yVel += this.gForce;
} else if (this.y + this.radio > GROUND && this.yVel > MIN_ACCELERATION) {
  this.yVel *= -this.friction;
  this.y = GROUND - this.radio;
  this.friction -= FRICTION_INCREASE;
} else {
  this.yVel = 0; // <---- STOP CASE
  this.y = GROUND - this.radio;
  this.run = false;
}
```

The above is the code we will be working on.

---

To graps what is the problem I deviced a way to debug it visually. What I did is change the color of the balls depending on the condition. The first case will be cyan, the second magenta. Let's see what happens:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var canvas = {};
var ball = [];

canvas.obj = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.ctx = canvas.obj.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.obj.width;
canvas.height = canvas.obj.height;
canvas.clear = function() {
  canvas.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
canvas.preferences = function() {
  canvas.ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(210,210,210)';
  canvas.ctx.lineWidth = 1;
};

const FRICTION = .9;
const MIN_ACCELERATION = 1;
const FRICTION_INCREASE = .015;
const DIST = 20;
const N_BALLS = 50; // BALLS NUMBER
const GROUND = canvas.height;

var Object = function() {
  this.yVel = 0;
  this.gForce = 0.2;
  this.friction = FRICTION;
  this.full = false;
  this.run = true;
  this.stroke = 'rgb(210,210,210)';

  this.draw = function() {
    canvas.ctx.beginPath();
    canvas.ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radio, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    canvas.ctx.strokeStyle = this.stroke;
    canvas.ctx.stroke();
  };

  this.physics = function() {

    this.y += this.yVel;

    if (this.y + this.radio < GROUND) {
      this.yVel += this.gForce;
    } else if (this.y + this.radio > GROUND && this.yVel > MIN_ACCELERATION) {
      this.yVel *= -this.friction;
      this.y = GROUND - this.radio;
      this.friction -= FRICTION_INCREASE;
      this.stroke = 'rgb(0,210,210)'; // Cyan
    } else {
      this.yVel = 0;
      this.y = GROUND - this.radio;
      this.run = false;
      this.stroke = 'rgb(210,0,210)'; // Magenta
    }
  };
};

var generateBalls = function(p) {

  var i, random;

  for (i = 0; i < N_BALLS; i++) {
    p[i] = new Object();

    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18) + 5;
    p[i].radio = random;

    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 22) + 1;
    p[i].x = DIST * random;

    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
    p[i].y = DIST * random;

  }
};

var drawBalls = function() {
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < N_BALLS; i++) {
    ball[i].draw();
  }
};

var applyPhysics = function() {
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < N_BALLS; i++) {
    ball[i].physics();
  }
};

generateBalls(ball);
canvas.preferences();
var program = setInterval(function() {

  canvas.clear();
  drawBalls();
  applyPhysics();

}, 1000 / 60);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid rgb(210, 210, 210);
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="400"></canvas>
<p id="output"></p>
```

As expected the balls turn magenta when they stop moving. This is just what we expected, we haven't discovered anything yet.

The next thing I will do is let the balls keep moving. This is the result:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var canvas = {};
var ball = [];

canvas.obj = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.ctx = canvas.obj.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.obj.width;
canvas.height = canvas.obj.height;
canvas.clear = function() {
  canvas.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
canvas.preferences = function() {
  canvas.ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(210,210,210)';
  canvas.ctx.lineWidth = 1;
};

const FRICTION = .9;
const MIN_ACCELERATION = 1;
const FRICTION_INCREASE = .015;
const DIST = 20;
const N_BALLS = 50; // BALLS NUMBER
const GROUND = canvas.height;

var Object = function() {
  this.yVel = 0;
  this.gForce = 0.2;
  this.friction = FRICTION;
  this.full = false;
  this.run = true;
  this.stroke = 'rgb(210,210,210)';

  this.draw = function() {
    canvas.ctx.beginPath();
    canvas.ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radio, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    canvas.ctx.strokeStyle = this.stroke;
    canvas.ctx.stroke();
  };

  this.physics = function() {

    this.y += this.yVel;

    if (this.y + this.radio < GROUND) {
      this.yVel += this.gForce;
    } else if (this.y + this.radio > GROUND && this.yVel > MIN_ACCELERATION) {
      this.yVel *= -this.friction;
      this.y = GROUND - this.radio;
      this.friction -= FRICTION_INCREASE;
      if (this.stroke == 'rgb(210,210,210)')
      {
          this.stroke = 'rgb(0,210,210)'; // Cyan
      }
    } else {
//        this.yVel = 0;
      this.y = GROUND - this.radio;
      this.run = false;
      this.stroke = 'rgb(210,0,210)'; // Magenta
    }
  };
};

var generateBalls = function(p) {

  var i, random;

  for (i = 0; i < N_BALLS; i++) {
    p[i] = new Object();

    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18) + 5;
    p[i].radio = random;

    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 22) + 1;
    p[i].x = DIST * random;

    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
    p[i].y = DIST * random;

  }
};

var drawBalls = function() {
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < N_BALLS; i++) {
    ball[i].draw();
  }
};

var applyPhysics = function() {
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < N_BALLS; i++) {
    ball[i].physics();
  }
};

generateBalls(ball);
canvas.preferences();
var program = setInterval(function() {

  canvas.clear();
  drawBalls();
  applyPhysics();

}, 1000 / 60);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid rgb(210, 210, 210);
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="400"></canvas>
<p id="output"></p>
```

---

We observe that the magenta balls keep bouncing. Thus we know that they had **speed** when they reached the stop case. This tell us that we were stopping them prematurely.

What we learned is that we are stopping the balls when they still had plenty of speed left. We shouldn't stop them until their speed is marginal.

---

Enough of visual debugging. Let us have a closer look at the code...

What is the logic to get to the stop case?

```
if (this.y + this.radio < GROUND) {
  // ...
} else if (this.y + this.radio > GROUND && this.yVel > MIN_ACCELERATION) {
  // ...
} else {
  // STOP CASE
}
```

To get there these must be false:

```
this.y + this.radio < GROUND
this.y + this.radio > GROUND && this.yVel > MIN_ACCELERATION
```

Provided that you have already checked `this.y + this.radio < GROUND` in the first conditional, we can assume that for the other cases this is true:

```
this.y + this.radio >= GROUND
```

Thus, the conditional

```
this.y + this.radio > GROUND && this.yVel > MIN_ACCELERATION
```

will fail in either of these situations:

```
this.y + this.radio == GROUND
this.yVel <= MIN_ACCELERATION
```

The first situaton is unlikely. We are not taking into account floating point errors in the comparisons. Still, it is worth noting that **if the ball happens to hit the ground perfectly, it will be stuck, regardless of speed**.

The second situation is problematic. Any negative value for `this.yVel` will pass `this.yVel <= MIN_ACCELERATION`. In this case a negative value is a downward speed, meaning that the ball should bounce.

---

To fix it. First, I suggest to only check for GROUND once. Here:

```
if (this.y + this.radio < GROUND) {
  // ...
} else if (this.yVel > MIN_ACCELERATION) {
  // ...
} else {
  // STOP CASE
}
```

This removes the edge situation where the ball is stuck because it hit the ground perfectly. It also makes it easier to reason about the other situation.

You want to bounce when the magnitud of `this.yVel` is greater than `MIN_ACCELERATION`. Then write that:

```
if (this.y + this.radio < GROUND) {
  // ...
} else if (Math.abs(this.yVel) > MIN_ACCELERATION) {
  // ...
} else {
  // STOP CASE
}
```

Now, you will reach the STOP case when these are false:

```
this.y + this.radio < GROUND
Math.abs(this.yVel) > MIN_ACCELERATION
```

In other words, to reach the stop case these must be true:

```
this.y + this.radio > GROUND
Math.abs(this.yVel) <= MIN_ACCELERATION
```

I know the first one is weird. It says that the ball is slightly burried in the ground. Although, as I said, there are floating point errors. The relevant part is that the speed of the ball has a very small magnitud. That is, it wouldn't have bounced too high. Now it is matter of tweaking `MIN_ACCELERATION` for your taste.

Let us see the result:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var canvas = {};
var ball = [];

canvas.obj = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.ctx = canvas.obj.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.obj.width;
canvas.height = canvas.obj.height;
canvas.clear = function() {
  canvas.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};
canvas.preferences = function() {
  canvas.ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(210,210,210)';
  canvas.ctx.lineWidth = 1;
};

const FRICTION = .9;
const MIN_ACCELERATION = 1;
const FRICTION_INCREASE = .015;
const DIST = 20;
const N_BALLS = 50; // BALLS NUMBER
const GROUND = canvas.height;

var Object = function() {
  this.yVel = 0;
  this.gForce = 0.2;
  this.friction = FRICTION;
  this.full = false;
  this.run = true;
  this.stroke = 'rgb(210,210,210)';

  this.draw = function() {
    canvas.ctx.beginPath();
    canvas.ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radio, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    canvas.ctx.strokeStyle = this.stroke;
    canvas.ctx.stroke();
  };

  this.physics = function() {

    this.y += this.yVel;

    if (this.y + this.radio < GROUND) {
      this.yVel += this.gForce;
    } else if (Math.abs(this.yVel) > MIN_ACCELERATION) {
      this.yVel *= -this.friction;
      this.y = GROUND - this.radio;
      this.friction -= FRICTION_INCREASE;
      if (this.stroke == 'rgb(210,210,210)')
      {
          this.stroke = 'rgb(0,210,210)'; // Cyan
      }
    } else {
      this.yVel = 0;
      this.y = GROUND - this.radio;
      this.run = false;
      this.stroke = 'rgb(210,0,210)'; // Magenta
    }
  };
};

var generateBalls = function(p) {

  var i, random;

  for (i = 0; i < N_BALLS; i++) {
    p[i] = new Object();

    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18) + 5;
    p[i].radio = random;

    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 22) + 1;
    p[i].x = DIST * random;

    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1;
    p[i].y = DIST * random;

  }
};

var drawBalls = function() {
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < N_BALLS; i++) {
    ball[i].draw();
  }
};

var applyPhysics = function() {
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < N_BALLS; i++) {
    ball[i].physics();
  }
};

generateBalls(ball);
canvas.preferences();
var program = setInterval(function() {

  canvas.clear();
  drawBalls();
  applyPhysics();

}, 1000 / 60);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid rgb(210, 210, 210);
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="400"></canvas>
<p id="output"></p>
```

I guess it is working correctly. The code depends on random... perhaps I am being lucky? I have confidence it is correct, I have tested it, it makes sense.

---

I could not help but think that having a repeatable test would have made things easier.

You are setting it up with random (which is ok for a data driven test), although, once you find a bug, we would advise to capture the initial conditions that lead to the bug and use them to make a reproducible test case.

In your particular problem, you may refactor the code to store a copy the initial conditions of the balls and write them to the console when they reach the stop case. If you can hardcode those the initial conditions, you can find situations when the ball gets stuck right away. That would serve as a test that predictably fails. Once you have that, it eaases debugging by stepping to you.

That is not a universal solution, racing conditions and other performance sensitive behavior creates “heisenbugs”, which resist repeatability.

---

If I had a test that didn't depend on random, I would have to guess it is working correctly. I would have evidence.

---

By the way, you are not using `this.run`. If you intend to use it as an optimization where you do not compute the motion of the ball when `this.run` is `true`. Then I suggest to remove the ball from the list instead, so that you don't even get an iteration for that ball... On that note, separate the list for physics from the list for drawing (that way you can remove them from the physics list but it will still be drawn). You would need that separation anyway if you want a large world and only draw what is visible to the "camera" but keep simulating the world.

---

There is another thing I want to mention: your physics assume the iterations happens at constant intervals. While `setInterval` should keep it relatively stable, there could be value in considering the elapsed time in the physics computation. Although that is not suitable for every game and it is off-topic for this question.

Comment: Excellent walkthrough on the debugging process, you sir earned my upvote

Comment: thanks for the debuggin specially the graphic one. It maybe be a realistic way to simulate a bounce, (gravity, weight, dimensions, fricction... etc) I'm just trying to get a lot of practice into oop. Anyway for response help me alot.